# Sobre fallback para CDN

Tags: javascript, cdn

Algumas pessoas recomendam utilizar a seguinte técnica (*fallback*) para carregar bibliotecas Javascript localmente caso o CDN esteja fora do ar:

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="jquery.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

A minha dúvida é: Se o CDN estiver mesmo fora do ar, o navegador não vai demorar vários segundos até considerar *timeout* e carregar a versão local? Isso tornaria a navegação lenta, pois a cada mudança de página ele tentaria novamente.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Na maioria dos tipos de `downtime`, **sim**, ficará lenta a página, mas **ao menos funcionará**.

Se o `downtime` for do tipo que responde rapidamente a indisponibilidade, como por exemplo, um erro interno, isto se resolverá rapidamente.

Quando ocorre downtime de servidores google, é muito comum vermos serviços como compra de passagens aéreas deixando de funcionar, então, o seu `fallback` é bem válido, como **medida de contenção de danos**.

Comment: Fora que a grande aposta ao se usar CDN é que o arquivo já exista em cache no browser, então o downtime pode acabar nem sendo notado.

Comment: o 2o script pode apontar para um outro CDN tbm ``<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="//outro.cdn.com/jquery.js"><\/script>')</script>``